# AODV Packet size in NS2 for IEEE 802.15.4 simulation

Tags: ns2

I am trying to do an IEEE 802.15.4 simulation in NS2 using AODV protocol. I am sending a 30-byte packet from node 0 to node 1. From the sender side, the packet is transferred with the added header. However, on the receiver side, the routing layer header is discarded in MAC layer but the MAC layer header is not discarded in AGT layer. I am sending 30-byte packet but receiving 50-byte packet. Am I doing anything wrong in my script? I have tried to simulate the code with IEEE 802.11 with AODV and it works perfectly.

I have attached the complete TCL script and Trace file lines for packet 0.

TCL Script

```
#===================================
#     Simulation parameters setup
#===================================
set val(chan)   Channel/WirelessChannel     ;# channel type
set val(prop)   Propagation/Shadowing       ;# radio-propagation model
set val(netif)  Phy/WirelessPhy/802_15_4    ;# network interface type
set val(mac)    Mac/802_15_4                ;# MAC type
set val(ifq)    Queue/DropTail/PriQueue     ;# interface queue type
set val(ll)     LL                          ;# link layer type
set val(ant)    Antenna/OmniAntenna         ;# antenna model
set val(ifqlen) 50                          ;# max packet in ifq
set val(nn)     2                           ;# number of mobilenodes
set val(rp)     AODV                        ;# routing protocol
set val(x)      1000                        ;# X dimension of topography
set val(y)      1000                        ;# Y dimension of topography
set val(stop)   2                       ;# time of simulation end

##################################################################

#===================================
Antenna/OmniAntenna set Gt_ 1                   ;#Transmit antenna gain
Antenna/OmniAntenna set Gr_ 1                   ;#Receive antenna gain
Phy/WirelessPhy     set L_ 1.0                  ;#System Loss Factor
Phy/WirelessPhy     set freq_ 2.4e9             ;#channel
Phy/WirelessPhy     set bandwidth_ 0.25Mb       ;#Data Rate


###############Simulation experiment # 3 ################################################
Phy/WirelessPhy set Pt_ 0.00050118723363            ;#in W for Transmit Power -3dBm IEEE 802.15.4 standard
Phy/WirelessPhy set RXThresh_ 3.1622776602e-12      ;#Receive Power Threshold  -85dBm   IEEE 802.15.4
Phy/WirelessPhy set CSThresh_ 1.5848931925e-12     ;#Carrier Sense Power   -88dBm

#===================================
#        Initialization        
#===================================
#Create a ns simulator
set ns [new Simulator]

#Setup topography object
set topo       [new Topography]
$topo load_flatgrid $val(x) $val(y)
create-god $val(nn)

#Open the NS trace file
set tracefile [open outAODV.tr w]
$ns trace-all $tracefile

#Open the NAM trace file
set namfile [open outAODV.nam w]
$ns namtrace-all $namfile
$ns namtrace-all-wireless $namfile $val(x) $val(y)
set chan [new $val(chan)];#Create wireless channel


#===================================
#     Mobile node parameter setup
#===================================
$ns node-config -adhocRouting  $val(rp) \
                -llType        $val(ll) \
                -macType       $val(mac) \
                -ifqType       $val(ifq) \
                -ifqLen        $val(ifqlen) \
                -antType       $val(ant) \
                -propType      $val(prop) \
                -phyType       $val(netif) \
                -channel       $chan \
                -topoInstance  $topo \
                -agentTrace    ON \
                -routerTrace   ON \
                -macTrace      ON \
                -movementTrace ON


# first set values of shadowing model
Propagation/Shadowing set pathlossExp 2.9  ;# path loss exponent
Propagation/Shadowing set std_db 8.0       ;# shadowing deviation (dB)
Propagation/Shadowing set dist0 1.0        ;# reference distance (m)
Propagation/Shadowing set seed 10           ;# seed for RNG


#===================================
#        Nodes Definition        
#===================================
set n0 [$ns node]                       ;#considered as a sink
$n0 set X_ 60
$n0 set Y_ 60
$n0 set Z_ 0.0
$ns initial_node_pos $n0 15

set n1 [$ns node]                       ;# Source 1 measured PDR /throughput / Delay varying diatance
$n1 set X_ 90
$n1 set Y_ 60
$n1 set Z_ 0.0
$ns initial_node_pos $n1 15

# Start Coordinate/Normal Nodes
$ns at 0.0  "$n0 NodeLabel \"PAN Coor\""
$ns at 0.0  "$n0 sscs startCTPANCoord"  

#===================================
#        Agents Definition        
#===================================
#Setup a UDP connection 
set null0 [new Agent/Null]      
$ns attach-agent $n0 $null0

#===================================
#        Applications Definition     CBR1      
#===================================
#Setup a CBR Application over UDP connection

set udp1 [new Agent/UDP]
$ns attach-agent $n1 $udp1
$ns connect $udp1 $null0

set cbr1 [new Application/Traffic/CBR]
$cbr1 attach-agent $udp1
$cbr1 set packetSize_ 30
$cbr1 set interval_ .1

$ns at 1.0 "$cbr1 start"
$ns at 1.5 "$cbr1 stop"

#===================================
#        Termination        
#===================================
#Define a 'finish' procedure
proc finish {} {
    global ns tracefile namfile
    $ns flush-trace
    close $tracefile
    close $namfile
    exec nam out.nam &
    exit 0
}
for {set i 0} {$i < $val(nn) } { incr i } {
    $ns at $val(stop) "\$n$i reset"
}
$ns at $val(stop) "$ns nam-end-wireless $val(stop)"
$ns at $val(stop) "finish"
$ns at $val(stop) "puts \"done\" ; $ns halt"
$ns run
```

Output Trace File (For Packet 0 Only)

```
s 1.000000000 _1_ AGT  --- 0 cbr 30 [0 0 0 0] ------- [1:0 0:0 32 0] [0] 0 0
r 1.000000000 _1_ RTR  --- 0 cbr 30 [0 0 0 0] ------- [1:0 0:0 32 0] [0] 0 0
s 1.000000000 _1_ RTR  --- 0 AODV 48 [0 0 0 0] ------- [1:255 -1:255 30 0] [0x2 1 1 [0 0] [1 4]] (REQUEST)
s 1.000665000 _1_ MAC  --- 0 AODV 55 [0 ffffffff 1 800] ------- [1:255 -1:255 30 0] [0x2 1 1 [0 0] [1 4]] (REQUEST)
r 1.003257100 _0_ MAC  --- 0 AODV 48 [0 ffffffff 1 800] ------- [1:255 -1:255 30 0] [0x2 1 1 [0 0] [1 4]] (REQUEST)
r 1.003282100 _0_ RTR  --- 0 AODV 48 [0 ffffffff 1 800] ------- [1:255 -1:255 30 0] [0x2 1 1 [0 0] [1 4]] (REQUEST)
s 1.003282100 _0_ RTR  --- 0 AODV 44 [0 0 0 0] ------- [0:255 1:255 30 1] [0x4 1 [0 4] 10.000000] (REPLY)
s 1.004352000 _0_ MAC  --- 0 ARP 35 [0 ffffffff 0 806] ------- [REQUEST 0/0 0/1]
r 1.006304100 _1_ MAC  --- 0 ARP 28 [0 ffffffff 0 806] ------- [REQUEST 0/0 0/1]
s 1.006629100 _1_ MAC  --- 0 ARP 35 [0 0 1 806] ------- [REPLY 1/1 0/0]
s 1.008192000 _0_ MAC  --- 0 ACK 5 [0 1 0 0] 
r 1.008544100 _1_ MAC  --- 0 ACK 5 [0 1 0 0] 
r 1.009184000 _0_ MAC  --- 0 ARP 28 [0 0 1 806] ------- [REPLY 1/1 0/0]
s 1.012032000 _0_ MAC  --- 0 AODV 51 [0 1 0 800] ------- [0:255 1:255 30 1] [0x4 1 [0 4] 10.000000] (REPLY)
s 1.014048100 _1_ MAC  --- 0 ACK 5 [0 0 1 0] 
r 1.014400200 _0_ MAC  --- 0 ACK 5 [0 0 1 0] 
r 1.015040100 _1_ MAC  --- 0 AODV 44 [0 1 0 800] ------- [0:255 1:255 30 1] [0x4 1 [0 4] 10.000000] (REPLY)
r 1.015065100 _1_ RTR  --- 0 AODV 44 [0 1 0 800] ------- [0:255 1:255 30 1] [0x4 1 [0 4] 10.000000] (REPLY)
s 1.015065100 _1_ RTR  --- 0 cbr 50 [0 0 0 0] ------- [1:0 0:0 30 0] [0] 0 0
s 1.017650100 _1_ MAC  --- 0 cbr 57 [0 0 1 800] ------- [1:0 0:0 30 0] [0] 0 0
s 1.020032000 _0_ MAC  --- 0 ACK 5 [0 1 0 0] 
r 1.020384100 _1_ MAC  --- 0 ACK 5 [0 1 0 0] 
r 1.021024000 _0_ MAC  --- 0 cbr 50 [0 0 1 800] ------- [1:0 0:0 30 0] [0] 1 0
r 1.021049000 _0_ AGT  --- 0 cbr 50 [0 0 1 800] ------- [1:0 0:0 30 0] [0] 1 0
```

Answer (score 1):

there are many deffernt parameters need to be modefied when using lr-wpan instead of wifi.
if you want to build IEE802.15.4 based wireless sensor network
you can find useful examples in this path

```
.\ns-allinone-2.35\ns-2.35\tcl\ex\wpan
```

use them as a template, or make benefit of them to modify your code.

also this book explains these examples

```
.....\ns-allinone-2.35\ns-2.35\wpan\WPAN_ZBR_pub.pdf
```

regards